# Set UIBarButtonItem animated not working on iOS 11

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, ios11, uinavigationitem

Since iOS 11, the `animated` parameter seems to be ignored in `setLeftBarButtonItems( _, animated: Bool)`, `setRightBarButtonItems(_, animated:)`, `setLeftBarButton(_, animated:)`, `setRightBarButton(_, animated:)` methods.

I made this simple code for a `UIViewController` subclass:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(changeRightBarButtonItem(_:)))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
}

@objc
func changeRightBarButtonItem(_ sender: Any) {
    let newRightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain,
                                             target: self, action: #selector(changeRightBarButtonItem(_:)))
    navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([newRightButton], animated: true)
}
```

This is running as expected on iOS 10 but on iOS 11 there is no differences whether `animated` is `true` or `false`.

It seems like it's an iOS 11 but maybe I missed something. Any hint to make it work? Even a workaround would be interesting.

Comment: did you add gif file that shows animation in ios 10 so we can easily understand your problem

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: No but it works again in the simulator on iOS 11.2 beta. I haven't tested yet on a device.

Comment: Still not working for me in 11.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in iOS 11 navbar's implementation.

Quoting:

These `setLeftBarButtonItem:animated:`, `setRightBarButtonItem:animated:`, `setLeftBarButtonItems:animated:`, and `setRightBarButtonItems:animated:` are not really animating items at all.

I think it's also an iOS 11 implementation bug, because in the chain of call from these mtehods are evenatually calling `updateTopNavigationItemAnimated:`, however, the current implementation is like this.

```
-[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS updateTopNavigationItemAnimated:]:
0000000000be5708         push       rbp
; Objective C Implementation defined at 0x13ff050 (instance method), DATA XREF=0x13ff050
0000000000be5709         mov        rbp, rsp
0000000000be570c         mov        rsi, qword [0x147f030]
; @selector(setupTopNavigationItem), argument "selector" for method _objc_msgSend
0000000000be5713         pop        rbp
0000000000be5714         jmp        qword [_objc_msgSend_11195c8]
; _objc_msgSend
```

Obvisouly, this method ignores given animated argument and simply calls `setupTopNavigationItem` which doesn't take any arugments. Thus, animated flag is ignored at this point.

Because of this implementation, seems like, in some cases, UIBarButton sometimes remains pressed state.

Source: https://gist.github.com/niw/569b49648fcab22124e1d12c195fe595